# Subir imagenes al index con MVC 4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo en mi vista "Subida" el siguiente codigo:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Y en mi controlador "SubidaController" el siguiente

```
public ActionResult Subida()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Necesito que desde el formulario de mi vista pueda cargar una imagen para luego ir al index y verla allí. Es decir que al subir una imagen se debe guardar dentro de un directorio físico de mi proyecto asi al reiniciar o recargar la pagina las imágenes no se pierden. 
He buscado he intentado los métodos que usan sitios como este [http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A09ZS.jpg) pero no he logrado lo que necesito.

*Editado*

Aqui encontre la forma de hacerlo, el unico problema que tengo es que no se muestran en mi pagina de Inicio, solamente se guardan en la carpeta "images" de mi proyecto [http://www.dotnetdreamer.net/upload-imagedisplay-image-in-aspnet-mvc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZMUg.jpg)

Subida View
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SubidaController
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HomeController
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bienvenido a SOes, hay diversas maneras de lograr lo que dices, aqui te doy una sencilla:

En el controlador donde realizas el `GET` del `Index`

```
ViewBag.Imagen = Server.MapPath("~") + @"Content\Images\ImagenAMostrar.png";
```

En la vista

```
 <img src="@ViewBag.Imagen" alt="IMAGES" />
```

Éxitos y bendiciones con la programación, dale con todo el power 2.0! Vas por buen camino :D

**Actualización**

La carpeta `Uploads` la tengo en la raiz del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el controlador `Home`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<string> listaRutaImagenes = new List<string>();
        var carpeta = Server.MapPath("~") + @"Uploads";
        //Necesitas: using System.IO; para realizar esto
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(carpeta);
        //Obtenemos todos los .jpg
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpg");          
        //Recorremos la carpeta
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            listaRutaImagenes.Add(file.Name);
        }
        ViewBag.lista = listaRutaImagenes;
        return View();
    }
```

En la vista: Views\Home\Index :

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.lista)
    {
        <img src="~/Uploads/@item" width="300" height="300" alt="" />
    }
```

Dando como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41282/discussion-on-answer-by-fredyfx-subir-imagenes-al-index-con-mvc-4-c).